# Android Play integrity api samples possibly xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am looking for way to secure my apps in both Android and iOS.

Android
Noticed that there is this new api [Play Integrity Api](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity)

I am looking for any example on usage Ideally in c# Xamarin , but I guess any example might be a starting point and see if can be ported to xamarin.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find Play Integrity Api sample for Xamarin, it seems that it is available only for Java, Kotlin, and Unity. I suggest that for now, you protect your app [with Dotfuscator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/protecting-xamarin-apps-dotfuscator/).

For android, you can also [Protect against security threats with SafetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet) here is the Xamarin version [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.SafetyNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.SafetyNet/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already got an implementation with SafetyNet but as you know SafetyNet is kind of deprecated. Dotfuscator is a no go for commercial app as it;s way to expensive, pity I cannot find anything in xamarin ...

Comment: Have you tried to create a Xamarin binding with native aar of Play Integrity package?

Comment: No I didnt I have not done binding before.. should it not be already done by the XFTeam?

Comment: Xamarin bindings for Play Integrity are now available. [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.Integrity/)

Comment: Hi @developer9969, I think I saw your question in github without a concrete answer about DeviceCheck of iOS: [link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/14272 )  I want to know you manage to make it work in Xamarin.iOS?  I almost did, but when calling DCAppAttestService.SharedService.AttestKeyAsync(keyId, HashValue);    I  am getting this error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.devicecheck.error error 2.) Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'Platform name: 5.').  Can you help me?

Comment: Hi @ShubhamAgarwal , i installed the nuget package you mentioned in link , and run the app, but its throwing app check token missing exception. Do you know how to set app check token with this nuget ?